# Two WSDL(s) have couple of common elements which results in exception while deploying code in Weblogic server

Tags: java, xml, binding, wsdl

My service is consuming two WSDL(s) (on which I have no control). Both these WSDL(s) have `AcctID` and `AcctPlstcID` elements, due to which I am unable to deploy service. Weblogic gets confused as it finds more than one mapping for these elements. I am getting following exception -

> *The element name {http://example.com/abc/V1}AcctID has more than one mapping.
>   this problem is related to the following location:
>   at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.xyz.ts2ccaccountstatusis.v1.ObjectFactory.createAcctID(java.lang.String)
>   at com.xyz.ts2ccaccountstatusis.v1.ObjectFactory
>   this problem is related to the following location:
>   at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.xyz.ts2cconLineservicingis.v1.ObjectFactory.createAcctID(java.lang.String)
>   at com.xyz.ts2cconLineservicingis.v1.ObjectFactory*

Please help me find a way to either fix  this issue or find a workaround.

Thank you in advance.